# Android & Google Maps crashes on client phone

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a tabview that loads a mapview and when I test the code on my phone it works, but if I export the APK and send it to the client, it crashes when they open it.  They are in a different part of the country so getting any useful info out of them has been limited.

My phone is running 2.2.1

Their phone is running 2.3.4

I'm using android:minSdkVersion="7" in the manifest.

I have tried using various versions of the Google api libs 2.3.3 works on mine but not for them  Google 2.1 works on mine but not theirs.

The rest of the app work, just the maps crashes on mine.

3.0 and later all crash out on mine for some reason.

Here's the map class:

```
public class GPSLocatorActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener  {
  private MapView map=null;
  private MyLocationOverlay me=null;
  private LocationManager lm;
  private MyLocationOverlay lo;
  private double latit;
  private double lonit;
  private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> thelist;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initLocation();
    map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
  //json stuff
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, myjasonfeedurlString>>();
   // Log.e("log_tag", "here we are at url "+latit);
    String url = "http://myjsonlocation/json.php?la=" + latit + "&lo=" + lonit;
    //Log.e("log_tag", "here is url "+url);
    JSONObject json =  getJSONfromURL(url);

    try{
    JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("locations");
    //Loop the Array
    for(int i=0;i < earthquakes.length();i++){                      

    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);
    hmap.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
    hmap.put("name", e.getString("name"));
    hmap.put("latitude", e.getString("lat"));
    hmap.put("longitude", e.getString("lon"));
    hmap.put("street", e.getString("street"));
    //Log.e("log_tag", "Here's what I pulled "+e.getString("name"));
    mylist.add(hmap);
    }
    thelist = mylist;
    } 
    catch(JSONException e)        {
    // Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
   map.getController().setCenter(getPoint(latit,
           lonit));
    map.getController().setZoom(14);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball24);

    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                            marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

    map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker));

    me=new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
    map.getOverlays().add(me);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

   // me.enableCompass();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    lo.disableMyLocation();
   // me.disableCompass();
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return(false);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
      map.setSatellite(!map.isSatellite());
      return(true);
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z) {
      map.displayZoomControls(true);
      return(true);
    }

    return(super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
  }

  private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
    return(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1000000.0),
                          (int)(lon*1000000.0)));
  }

  private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
      super(marker);

      boundCenterBottom(marker);
        for(int i=0;i < thelist.size();i++){  
            Map<String, String> hmap = thelist.get(i);
            double tlo = Double.valueOf(hmap.get("longitude"));
            double tla = Double.valueOf(hmap.get("latitude"));
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(tla*1E6),(int)(tlo*1E6));
            //Log.e("log_tag","geopoint : " + point +" me "+ (int)(latit*1000000.0) + " , " +(int)(lonit*1000000.0));

            items.add(new OverlayItem(point,hmap.get("name"), hmap.get("street")));

        }  


      items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(0.748963847316034,
                                          -123.96807193756104),
                                "blank", "placeholder"));

      populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return(items.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
      Toast.makeText(GPSLocatorActivity.this,
                      items.get(i).getTitle() + " @ " + items.get(i).getSnippet(),
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      return(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
      return(items.size());
    }
  }
    private void initLocation(){

        lm= (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 500, this);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
       // Log.e("log_tag", "lat "+ latitude);
       // Log.e("log_tag", "lon: "+ longitude);
        latit = latitude;
        lonit = longitude;
}



    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        List overlays = map.getOverlays();
        lo = new MyLocationOverlay(this,map);
        overlays.add(lo);
        lo.enableMyLocation();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    //json
    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

        //initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            //Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //try parse the string to a JSON object
        try{
                jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            //Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
    //json


}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  I haven't worked with maps much yet.

Thanks

Comment: OK.  I added bugsense and I have a null pointer on location.  at  double longitude = location.getLongitude();

Comment: I think you just answered your own question..

Comment: the crazy thing is even if I catch the null and give the variable a hardcoded lat, it is crashing.  Bugsense reports the gps as off on the client phone, but they assure me they turned it on.  I have both fine access and coarse on in manifest.  I really don't like maps right now.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a BugSense account and integrate it into your app so you can track crashes on other devices. Until you know what the exception is, it's going to be very hard to know what the cause is.

http://www.bugsense.com/